# Get super class node/name from compilation unit or ast tree

Tags: eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, superclass

I have a ast object for a compilation unit. How can I get superclass object from the ast tree?

Thanks.

Comment: I found an answer: I had to implement a visitor for AST tree with TypeDeclaration argument and get the super class using node.resolveBinding().getSuperclass()